# printf and %s in C

Tags: c, printf, buffer-overflow

I understand that this code segment is supposed to have a buffer overflow vulnerability problem:

```
printf("File %s", my_file_name);
printf("File %s");
```

However, I don't get exactly why it is considered risky. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: What you've posted here has a buffer underflow issue.  You tell printf that there's a string on the stack but don't give it one.  Unless my_file_name is pointing at more data than the space allocated for it, this is not a buffer overflow situation

Comment: This seems like a good answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43574/how-is-printf-in-c-c-a-buffer-overflow-vulnerability

Comment: Mmm.. the printf answer there is a format string vulnerability, not a buffer overflow @crclayton

Comment: I would almost assume that any buffer overflow issues concern `ssprintf`, when the output is copied to a buffer and the format contains a `%s`  without a field length. Such code has run very well for years (from the 70s into the 90s, roughly) until malicious, overly long data is passed, which will be written beyond the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below outputs the contents of `my_file_name` to the standard output:

```
printf("File %s", my_file_name);
```

If `my_file_name` is received from a malicious source and the program outputs to the terminal, it is possible for the malicious source to have put escape sequences in `my_file_name` that tell the terminal to perform non trivial tasks such as sending terminal contents back through standard input.  It is difficult but conceivable that an attacker may derive useful information from such an attack or even attempt to corrupt data via executing commands as if they were typed by the user.

Of course the second call invokes undefined behavior as you are not passing a valid string pointer as a second argument to `printf`.

The above scenario is probably not what you are referring to by *buffer overflow vulnerability*.  There is no such vulnerability in the `printf` code it self, but is a buffer overflow flaw exists somewhere else in your code, and the actual format string can be patched via this overflow, an attacker can take advantage of `printf`'s capabilities, especially the `%n` format to poke any value to almost any location in the program memory.  This is the rationale for removing `%n` in `printf_s` as exposed in a Microsoft security paper.

Comment: Well, this is not a "buffer overflow vulnerability". It will also only work for specific terminals and operating systems, and for output which indeed goes to a terminal. Typical services like ftp, http servers will usually have stdout redirected somewhere. Interactive programs, otoh, ususlly have the user sitting at a terminal anyway, so no gain. Unlikely scenario. Do you have an example?

Comment: Peter, I was not sure when I said it had a buffer overflow issue. That was only my rudimentary understanding. Whether or not that is still the case, I have no idea. But this answer explains the security vulnerability rather nicely. (Edit: I see this has been edited into the answer.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: That's correct, I amended the answer to this regard.  Regarding the terminal abuse scenario, it used to be a classic attack in Unix 4.1 BSD when ttys could be written to by any process.

Answer (score 2):

The first call is fine. (Issues exist when you use a user provided format string, as in `printf(s)`, where s is under the influence of the user. Here you use a hard-coded format string `"File %s"`, which is not vulnerable. The contents of the string `my_file_name` will be treated as a regular C string and just be copied to the standard output. Of course it must be null terminated, and if the output is redirected to something else there can be side effects there, but that's not a printf issue.)

The second call is simply undefined behavior, because the number of parameters after the format string (0) does not match the number which the format string demands (1).